When to store store plugin options as a single database record?
I'm building the analytics script plugin which offers customizations on a settings page. There will be around 20 options in total.
Does it affect the performance negatively if I manage these 20 options separately? So each of them will have a database record instead of storing it all as one.
I remember that all options will get preloaded on every page in WordPress anyway unless explicitly specified not to when registering a setting.

It shouldn’t affect performance to store each option in a separate row. The PHP application is capable of fetching multiple rows in a single batch and, in fact, WordPress itself stores its settings one per row.
I recommend using the Options API so that WordPress does most of the work for you.
https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/options/
As suggested on the WordPress Forum by one of the team members.

If you are looking for performance and have 20 options so yes it is better to store in 1 option key in serialize() manner.

Thank you, but could you specify how exactly storing them separately affects the performance?

If you use WP then you would be calling get_option() for your 20 options and it will result in 20 SQL queries and if you store by serializing in only 1 get_option() so your get_options you just need to call 1 SQL query and then unserialize it.

From my understanding, WordPress preloads all options that have autoload=true in the database, meaning there will only be 1 SQL query on each page visit. Using get_option will just retrieve the already-fetched option data.

Please check use of autoload=true here - https://docs.wpvip.com/wordpress-on-vip/autoloaded-options/

Also it is not advisable to set autoload=true for your custom option_key and value

I checked the article and it only mentions that the total size of all options should not exceed 1MB. Considering how big 1MB of text is, I don't see why using autoload=true for custom options is a problem.
